# wrapall direct sibling classes into their own divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal, siblings

I want to wrap direct sibling groups of classes starting by 'ok' into their own 
http://jsfiddle.net/7hABQ/12/

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="ok-4"></div>
<div class="ok-87"></div>
<div class="ok-11"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="baz"></div>
<div class="ok-5a4"></div>
<div class="ok-12"></div>
<div class="bim">iii</div>
```

into this:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="ok-4"></div>
    <div class="ok-87"></div>
    <div class="ok-11"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="baz"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="ok-5a4"></div>
    <div class="ok-12"></div>
</div>
<div class="bim">iii</div>
```

Comment: So did it work? If not, can you tell us what's wrong?

Comment: no it is only an indicator of what i have so far (in jsfiddle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
$(':not(div[class^="ok"]) + div[class^="ok"]').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(':not(div[class^="ok"])')
           .addBack()
           .wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7hABQ/18/

Comment: Yes it is a great idea! Thank you Vision and Rajaprobhu too.